# How I get privacy policy for my app on play store?

Tags: android, google-play, privacy-policy

recently Play Store ordered that all apps should have a privacy policy. I really don't know how to do it and if I really must do it, because my apps don't collect any data from user (no name, no location or ...). Can someone help me how to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not collect any data (including through use of third-party SDKs), simply state so in a Privacy Policy [3]. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08ZEd.jpg):

[image]

[3] https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/privacy-policy-no-data-collected/

Answer (score -1):

You can generate free privacy policy using this useful website [freeprivacypolicy](https://www.freeprivacypolicy.com/).

Comment: But they request what the app collects from user, but my app doesn't collect anything!

Comment: You do not have to select. Just skip and select others.